# fabric.js works with subclass

Tags: subclass, fabricjs

I try to create new class working with fabric.js framework. This class should consist of 3 simple objects: 2 text and 1 rectangle. One of text object should be updated by time, for example each second. The problem is new value does not appear on canvas as expected, but it updates every time when you select object. Here is my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/a_popov/5n453z6d/3/). Could anyone explain me, what should I do to make it updates by time?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    
fabric.Tag = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    type: 'PItag',
    
    initialize: function() {
    
        options = {};
    
        options.top     = 0;
        options.left    = 0;
    
        var defaults    = {
            width:  100,
            height: 40,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        };
    
        var defaults1    = {
            width:  100,
            height: 20,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'top',
            top: -20,
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        };
    
        var defaults2    = {
            width:  100,
            height: 20,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'top',
            top: 0
        };
    
        var items   = [];
    
        items[0]    = new fabric.Rect($.extend({}, defaults, {
            fill: '#77AAFF',
        }));
    
        items[1]    = new fabric.Textbox('PI tag name', $.extend({}, defaults1, {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 14
        }));
    
        items[2]    = new fabric.IText('####', $.extend({}, defaults2, {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 16
        }));
    
        this.callSuper('initialize', items, options);
    
    },
    
    getTagName: function () {
        return this._objects[1].text;
    },
    
    setTagName: function (value) {
        this._objects[1].text = value;
    },
    
    getValue: function () {
        return this._objects[2].text;
    },
    
    setValue: function (value) {
        this._objects[2].text = value;
        this.canvas.renderAll();
    },
    
    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);          
    }
    
});

var pi = new fabric.Tag();
    
pi.setTagName("Unix time");
canvas.add(pi);
    
setInterval(function() {
    pi.setValue(Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000).toString());
    canvas.renderAll();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Tag = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
 type: 'PItag',

initialize: function() {

    options = {};
    options.left = 100;
    options.top=100;

    var defaults    = {
        width:  100,
        height: 40,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center'
    };

    var defaults1    = {
        width:  100,
        height: 20,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        top: -20,
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    };

    var defaults2    = {
        width:  100,
        height: 20,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'top',
        top: 0
    };

    var items   = [];

    items[0]    = new fabric.Rect($.extend({}, defaults, {
        fill: '#77AAFF',
    }));

    items[1]    = new fabric.Textbox('PI tag name', $.extend({}, defaults1, {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14
    }));

    items[2]    = new fabric.IText('####', $.extend({}, defaults2, {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 16
    }));

    this.callSuper('initialize', items, options);

},

getTagName: function () {
    return this._objects[1].text;
},

setTagName: function (value) {
    this._objects[1].text = value;
},

getValue: function () {
    return this._objects[2].text;
},

setValue: function (value) {
    this._objects[2].set({ text: value });
    this.canvas.renderAll();
},

_render: function(ctx,noTransform) {

console.log('xs')
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    //ctx._objects[1].text = this._objects[1].text;

}

});
var pi = new fabric.Tag();
// canvas.pi.async = true;
pi.setTagName("Unix time");

  canvas.add(pi);
setInterval(function() {

 pi.setValue(Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000).toString());
  canvas.renderAll();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas  id="c" height="418" width="400" style="border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);"></canvas>
```

just change this function 
`setValue: function (value) {
    this._objects[2].set({ text: value });
    this.canvas.renderAll();
},`